# What are all the subfields of $\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{4}}, q^{\frac{1}{2}})$ for any two distinct primes $p,q$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, extension-field

> What are all the subfields of $\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{4}}, q^{\frac{1}{2}})$ for any two distinct primes $p,q$?

From my intuition, I think that the degree $4$ subfields are $A=\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{2}}, q^{\frac{1}{2}})$, $B=\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{4}})$, and $C=\mathbb Q(q^{\frac{1}{2}}p^{\frac{1}{4}})$, and the degree $2$ subfields are $\mathbb Q(q^{\frac{1}{2}}p^{\frac{1}{2}})$ in $A$, $\mathbb Q(q^{\frac{1}{2}})$ in $A$, and $\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{2}})$ in all $A, B, C$. But I don't know any rigorous way to prove that these are all the subfields and that there are no other subfields. I want to use Galois theory to find a corresponding Galois group but  $\mathbb Q(p^{\frac{1}{4}}, q^{\frac{1}{2}})$ is not Galois. So I am not sure which procedure to take.

Comment: You can consider the normal closure of your field. That one is Galois, so you can find the structure of its subfields using Galois theory. And since your original field is a subfield of its normal closure, you automatically get to know about the subfields of your original field as well (since those subfields are also subfields of the normal closure).